# UI grid expandable row with subgrid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have been struggling trying to achieve something like this using UI grid but have failed miserably.
I tried using UI Grid expandable row option as well as UI grid tree option.

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/216_expandable_grid

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/2104

Tree view in UI Grid has something similar but expanding row has same now of columns as the header.
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/215_treeView
Can someone guide me to achieve something like this.

[image]

and when I click on a particular row I get something like this

[image]

Basically the top header and expanded field corresponding to header.

If someone has some other table option where I can achieve something like this?

Comment: Can you post the code you tried using UI-grid expandable row option that you could not get to work?

Comment: I just tried the same example code as given in the ui Gris expandable row and ui grid tree. Tried to mainpulate but couldn't achieve even close to what i needed.